# how to calculate factorial of list using higher order function in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to calculate factorial of elements present in a Scala list for suppose List(1,2,3) using Higher order function as in below code

```
object HigherOrderFunctionEg{
 def main(args :Array[String]){
  val input = args(0).toInt
    val intiList :List[Int] = List.range(1,input+1)
    def factorial(n: Int): Int = {
      if (n == 0) 
      return 1
      else
      return n * factorial(n-1)
     }
    def myHigherOrderFn (factorial : Int => Unit, intiList : List[Int]) : Unit = 
     {
   intiList.foreach(factorial)
    println(intiList.foreach(factorial))
    }
    myHigherOrderFn(factorial, intiList)
 }
}
```

When I am trying to scala HigherOrderFunctionEg.scala 3 I am getting output as only empty braces () where as I am expecting output like
1
2
6

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems:

1. `factorial` is `Int => Int` but you have used `Int => Unit`
2. `foreach` returns `Unit` so printing the result will always give `()`
3. `myHigherOrderFun` returns `Unit` so it isn't really a function.

This is a better way to write it:

```
def myHigherOrderFn(factorial: Int => Int, intiList: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  intiList.map(factorial)

myHigherOrderFn(factorial, intiList).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim... It optly served the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the return type of factorial is  `Int => Unit`. It should be  `Int => Int`

As it takes an integer and returns an integer.

You need to change your definition like this.

```
def myHigherOrderFn (factorial : Int => Int, intiList : List[Int]) : Unit =
    intiList.foreach(e => println(factorial(e)))
```